# How to change a wordpress post url dynamically without url re-write rule

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have a `$postURL`, which basically contains a wordpress post url. I retrieve it as follows:

```
$postURL = get_permalink($postID);
```

Now suppose this $postURL is:

```
http://www.blogname.come/post-permalink/
```

I want to change this to

```
http://www.blogname.come/post-permalink-1/
```

i.e. add a `-1` at the end of the $postURL and add it to a new variable `$newURL`.

// Function to include required JS and CSS in header
function wplikelockercss() {

```
// Include the CSS
echo "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".get_bloginfo('wpurl')."/wp-content/plugins/".basename(dirname(__FILE__))."/like-locker.css\"> \n";
//$postID = $_POST['post'];
$postID = get_the_ID();
$postURL = get_permalink($postID);
$newURL = substr($postURL, 0 -1). "-1";
//$newURL = "1-".$postURL;


// Echo our per page post ID callback from facebok, when the user clicks like this function will be triggerd and their IP will be stored in the databse with the post ID
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href){ 

        var data = { post: '".get_the_ID()."', action: 'fbjax' };

        jQuery.post('".admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )."', data, function(response) {

            //location.reload();
            //location.href='http://www.blogname.net/how-thing-work-1';
            location.href='$newURL';

        });

    });

</script> \n
";
```

}

The code that I have in place is provided above. I am getting the $postID, fetching the $postURL and then trying to create a newURL. The location.href then uses this $newURL to redirect users to a new page.

However, if is use

$newURL = substr($postURL, 0 -1). "-1";

The $newURL is

http://www.blogname.net/e-1 or someother character before -1

If i use

$newURL = "1-".$postURL;

The location.href redirects page to

http://www.blogname.net/1-

Answer (score 1):

Using htaccess, host Linux:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule post-permalink-1$ post-permalink
```

Answer (score 0):

`$newUrl = substr($postUrl, 0 -1) . "-1/";`

Comment: The code change that u suggest is not working. When i try to redirect from $postURL to $newURL in javascript using 

location.href='$newURL';

The same page is loaded again.

Comment: what you mean by  not working?  this code just cut of last symbol of $postURL, and add "-1/" string at and.

Comment: I tried it again and the  location.href='$newURL'; transfer to 

http://www.blogname.come/-1/

Instead of

http://www.blogname.come/post-permalink-1/

Comment: Try this $newUrl = substr($postURL, 0 -1) . "-1/"; I changed the posturl variable name. Thanks

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P I have added more details about the issue in my answer. I also thought initially that the issue is due to the postURL variable name

Comment: Thanks a lot friends. the code is working..I think i was doing something wrong. Thanks for ur help